# can we do voice calling in the iphone?

Tags: iphone

Can we do the voice identify functionality in the iphone os 3.0 i have some sound recorded by the user than on them i have to do some function can we do it in the os 3.0.

example code would be appreciated .

i mean can we do that like: we record our sound and after just click on the call button and than first we speak the name of the person and call goes to that one ??

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Translation - Can we do voice dialing in iphone OS 3.0

Answer (score 3):

This question is quite confusing, but I'll try to answer what I understand of it.

The iPhone 3GS, running iPhone OS 3.0, has voice dialing functionality, which can be accessed by holding down the home button or holding down the center button on the apple headphones.  Apple has not opened up any APIs to access voice dialing (or any of the other voice controlling features) to third party developers.

However, if you want to create your own voice recognition algorithms this can be done.  Google has created an app that lets you speak your desired search query into the phone and then it will translate the query into the appropriate text and perform the search.

Apple does allow calling a specified number from a third party app.  Use `teL:` followed by the appropriate number.

So if you want to implement voice dialing, you have to roll your own voice recognition/detection software, and then use the `teL:` URL to place the call.