# Voice Recognition in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have seen many application doing voice recognition on the iphone.

I have already gone through the following questions of stackoverflow:
-[iPhone App › Add voice recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition)
-[can we do voice calling in the iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208069/can-we-do-voice-calling-in-the-iphone)

However I couldn't find sufficient knowledge.

I have to develop an application which should have following functionality:

```
=>Store list of students in database => i can do
=>Retrieve in to tableView => i can do
=>Find student by voice recognition => dont know how?**
```

I don't know how to do the voice recognition part, can you guide me to correct way?

How to record a voice & search student accordingly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the previous SO answers lacking?

Comment: We all know that the iPhone has Voice Recognition ... we don't need videos to prove it..

Comment: @Chacha - ok i am removing links
@ceejayoz - ok, lacking sample code or any other suggestion that can be helpful to develop application.

Comment: There we go, all nice a formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look again at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208069/can-we-do-voice-calling-in-the-iphone).  Particularly:

> Apple has not opened up any APIs to access voice dialing (or any of the other voice controlling features) to third party developers.
>   However, if you want to create your own voice recognition algorithms this can be done.

You need to do it yourself somehow.
The other question you linked to has some good suggestions on that.

Comment: @Michael - Ok I understood that Apple hasn't opened up APIs. Than Any third party developers link can you provide plz?

Comment: @Michael - I am in a little confusion. if Apple hasn't opened up any APIs to access voice controlling features, then how google can?

Comment: They did it themselves, using the technique described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition

Also you could read this for more on how they did it:
http://joelaz.com/post/60338144/google-voice-recognition-voice-search-api

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using a third party tool for voice recognition,
you can visit this link:
http://www.voicevault.com/qtech.aspx?q=4