# Interaction with google voice recognition in iPhone? Possible?

Tags: iphone

Plz, go Through my Previous question?

---

[Voice Recognition in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240152/voice-recognition-in-iphone)

---

Ok Now my Current question is as below.

It seems very hard to build my own voice recognition code - in iPhone.

Is it possible to use google's voice recognition in our software,

like when user wants to search a student by voice
=>voice is recorded & searched by google
=>& it respond to my application,

ok. I understand my question is quite confusing.
However plz leave comment for me for correction.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's iPhone app does not do voice recognition on the phone, it records the audio, and then sends it to Google's servers which do the analysis. Some day Google may make webservices available to allow you to send generic clips and get back search results, but to my knowledge they do not provide anything like that at this time.

Since Google does not provide any API for their Voice Recognition the answer would seem to be no.

Comment: but android consists and supports google voice recognition in their sdk.how is it possible?