# API for Voice recognition in among group

Tags: iphone

Any API for this or any Help, plz tell me.
(I am thinking about this is through interaction to the server where will be the voice recognition parser or API etc..)

I am working on a iphone application in which i have to implement the voice recognition as
: four member will store their liking words(by speaking) one bye one in iphone.
after this they will store speech group discuss in iphone, if in this discussion they speak their liking words then i have to tell in text format who use his liking words and how many times.

Suppose:
A- store his liking word "Hello", 
B- store his liking word "Wow",
C- store his liking word "Mango",
D- store his liking word "Great"

if A,B,C,D use their words in discussion then need to tell in text form who use his liking words.

Any idea/reference/API  how to do this.

Thank,
Aaryan

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to refer to the answers in the following questions:

- ["iPhone App › Add voice recognition?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition)
- ["Voice Recognition in iPhone ?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240152/voice-recognition-in-iphone)
- ["iPhone speech recognition API?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121548/iphone-speech-recognition-api)

In short, there is no API for this on the iPhone, although there is a [private Voice Services framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102244/iphone-api-for-text-to-speech-feature/1103532#1103532) on the iPhone 3GS for going the other way, from text to speech.  Given the computational limitations of a portable device, your best bet would be to implement this voice recognition on a backend server, like Google does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't know any API that is capable of doing such a thing - but what about using a TTS (Text-To-Speech) API to store the liking word and the discussion and search in the discussion-text for the liking-words.