# APIs for converting Voice/Audio data in to text

Tags: iphone

I am working on a iphone apps in which i am storing the voice of users as audio file and want to display in text.

How it will be ...any idea about APIs ??

Thanks,
Aaryan

Comment: This is a commonly asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651051/api-for-voice-recognition-in-among-group, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240152/voice-recognition-in-iphone

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/html/cmusphinx.php) ?

Particularly, [pocket sphinx (written in C)](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/pocketsphinx/)

While more recognition oriented, [it's been used for transcription before](http://docs.google.com/gview?a=v&q=cache:QzZE1LstPPUJ:www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/speechLIUMtools/Downloads/LIUM_Interspeech05.pdf+LIUM+speech&hl=en&gl=us&sig=AFQjCNECRIgTlq5VpidHpYl8u2R8FlsBnQ), so it will depend on what exactly you need:

Further, have you considered a non-native/local API, i.e. a web service you could call with your voice data, or are you adamant about a native library/API ?

For example, [Ribbit has a platform for these sorts of things](http://developer.ribbit.com/platform), and does support transcribing voice to text

"How do I enable voice-to-text transcriptions?
Available as a paid service, voice-to-text transcriptions are automatically available through the Ribbit API. Please use the $25 Free signup credit to try the service."

Comment: Ribbit didnt begin this services yet and  Will begin APIs services from mid of December.

Answer (score 1):

There is one app that does this already: [Jott](http://jott.com/default.aspx).  The way they do it is to send the file to transcribers in India! ([source](http://venturebeat.com/2007/03/26/jott-a-convenient-voice-to-text-service/))

Answer (score 0):

You will have to develop the voice recognition engine yourself I'm afraid. No library that I know of can do this. Apart form that, the iPhone CPU would probably not be powerful enough.

Comment: will work.. there is for example "Dragon Dictation"... audio to text.. works fine :)