# Convert the voice to text in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to ask a question about the iPhone application. Does Apple provide any API to the developers to record the phone call and convert it to text message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone App › Add voice recognition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, there are no APIs for recording phone calls or converting text to speech.  You will need to create a speech recognition engine.  I suspect the iPhone hardware will not be powerful enough to handle that type of processing though.

FYI...

[APIs for converting Voice/Audio data in to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681990/apis-for-converting-voice-audio-data-in-to-text)

[API for Voice recognition in among group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651051/api-for-voice-recognition-in-among-group)

[iPhone speech recognition API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121548/iphone-speech-recognition-api)