# Displaying recoreded voice in table view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing a application which will store the voice and display recored voice in table view along with text what we speak, i am successfully able to record voice and play it back but i want to store all the recored voice in table view and play on my choice, can any one me to come out of this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Display voice...? first time hear this. You have to set just title of voice file that you saved in to local storage.

Comment: If your showing the recorded voice then, what's the point of showing text along with it?

Comment: actually what i want to display is what ever we speech that should record (Ex.How are you??)the same words should come on table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want to add Voice to text feature in your app.

This link will help you in [Convert the voice to text in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626108/convert-the-voice-to-text-in-iphone)

Comment: yo are right..successfully added that feature now i want to display al those in table view format

Comment: Can you tell more, where do you get problem, to display the text on table view. Where do you save the converted voice text?